# JS: displaying different timezones in specific format

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, timezone-offset

Okay so I have a feature I'm working on for a new site where I need to display current time for both East Coast and West Coast. It needs to be display in the following way:
NY 11:24:21 PM
CA 08:24:21 PM

Thus far I've managed to get the time zones to start displaying but I need to make sure they both are pointing specifically only to EST & PST and that they are displaying inside the proper html blocks. I also need the AM/PM to wrap inside a  html block.

Here is my sample code:

```js
function showTime() {
    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    let formatHours = convertFormat(hours)
    
    hours = checkTime(hours)
    hours = addZero(hours)
    minutes = addZero(minutes)
    seconds = addZero(seconds)
    let format = `NY ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} <small class="font-medium">${formatHours}</small>`
    let pstDate = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}, {timeStyle: 'short'})

    // Output Times
    $('.time-ny').html(format);
    $('.time-ca').html(pstDate);
}

function convertFormat(time) {
    let formmat = 'PM'
    if (time >= 12) {
        format = 'AM'
    }
    return formmat;
}

function checkTime(time) {
    if (time > 12) {
        time = time - 12;
    }
    if (time === 0) {
        time = 12;
    }
    return time
}

function addZero(time) {
    if (time < 10) {
        time = "0" + time;
    }
    return time
}
showTime()
setInterval(showTime, 1000)
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.clock {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.font-medium {
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock time-ny"></div>
<div class="clock time-ca"></div>
```

Any help from you real JS coders would be super appreciated. I dabble in this stuff but it will never be my bread and butter.

Comment: Oh my god! You're a saint. This perfectly solved my issue. Thank you so very much!

Comment: I just looked at the alternative solution and liked that even better. More concise. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two adjustments are needed in your code to make it work correctly:

1. Format the time string with the AM/PM wrapped in an HTML block.
2. Get the East Coast and West Coast times by using the [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method, and then pass it to a function which formats the time string(that mentioned above in point 1).

A sample would look like:

```js
function showTime() {
  let date = new Date();
  let estDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  }));
  let pstDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
  }));

  let formatNY = formatTime(estDate);
  let formatCA = formatTime(pstDate);

  // Output Times
  $('.time-ny').html(formatNY);
  $('.time-ca').html(formatCA);
}
// Created this method to format time.
function formatTime(date) {
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date.getSeconds();
  let formatHours = convertFormat(hours);

  hours = checkTime(hours);
  hours = addZero(hours);
  minutes = addZero(minutes);
  seconds = addZero(seconds);

  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} <small class="font-medium">${formatHours}</small>`;
}

function convertFormat(time) {
  let format = 'AM';
  if (time >= 12) {
    format = 'PM';
  }
  return format;
}

function checkTime(time) {
  if (time >= 12) {
    time = time - 12;
  }
  if (time === 0) {
    time = 12;
  }
  return time;
}

function addZero(time) {
  if (time < 10) {
    time = "0" + time;
  }
  return time;
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.clock {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.font-medium {
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock time-ny"></div>
<div class="clock time-ca"></div>
```

---

#### Alternative solution:

As a suggestion and alternative, you can also make your code concise by leveraging the [***`Intl`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object which is now provided in the language itself. A sample code would look like below:

```js
function showTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const estDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  }));
  const pstDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
  }));

  const formatNY = formatTime(estDate, 'NY');
  const formatCA = formatTime(pstDate, 'CA');

  // Output Times
  $('.time-ny').html(formatNY);
  $('.time-ca').html(formatCA);
}

function formatTime(date, label) {
  const timeFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: true,
  });

  const formattedTime = timeFormatter.format(date);
  const [time, period] = formattedTime.split(' ');

  return `${label} ${time} <small class="font-medium">${period}</small>`;
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.clock {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.font-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock time-ny"></div>
<div class="clock time-ca"></div>
```